# Using cshell for finding incomplete files

Tags: shell, size, csh

Does anyone know how can I check if a data file's size is smaller than a certain size X ( in C-shell) and then list that particular size and the file's name on the screen ?  In other words how to extract incomplete data files from a bunch of files that should have size X.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware if C-shell has any particular way of doing this, but it can be done with the GNU `find` utility:

```
# Bigger than 100MB
find $PATH -size +100M -printf '%p - %s'

# Smaller than 100MB
find $PATH -size -100M -printf '%p - %s'
```

`%p` stands for the file path, while `%s` stands for the file size in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

`stat -c "%s" filename.dat` should give you the file size in bytes, which you can then compare to your expected value.